# Why do the Borwein integrals stop being $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, divergent-series

I just received the book "single digits - In praise of Small Numbers" by Marc Chamberland.

In this book, he gives an interesting integral

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3}\dfrac{\sin(x/5)}{x/5} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3}\dfrac{\sin(x/5)}{x/5}\dfrac{\sin(x/7)}{x/7} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3}\dfrac{\sin(x/5)}{x/5}\dfrac{\sin(x/7)}{x/7} \dfrac{\sin(x/9)}{x/9}= \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3}\dfrac{\sin(x/5)}{x/5}\dfrac{\sin(x/7)}{x/7} \dfrac{\sin(x/9)}{x/9}\dfrac{\sin(x/11)}{x/11}= \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3}\dfrac{\sin(x/5)}{x/5}\dfrac{\sin(x/7)}{x/7} \dfrac{\sin(x/9)}{x/9}\dfrac{\sin(x/11)}{x/11}\dfrac{\sin(x/13)}{x/13} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

At this point, it is tempting to speculate that this pattern goes on forever, but we run into problems and this is another example of jumping to conclusions too soon.

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3}\dfrac{\sin(x/5)}{x/5}\dfrac{\sin(x/7)}{x/7} \dfrac{\sin(x/9)}{x/9}\dfrac{\sin(x/11)}{x/11}\dfrac{\sin(x/13)}{x/13}\dfrac{\sin(x/15)}{x/15} = \dfrac{467807924713440738696537864469 \pi }{935615849440640907310521750000}$$

I calculated the next several and they are nice approximations to the results above, but not that result

- $$\dfrac{17708695183056190642497315530628422295569865119 \pi }{35417390788301195294898352987527510935040000000}$$
- $$\dfrac{8096799621940897567828686854312535486311061114550605367511653 \pi }{16193600755941299921751838065715269433640150152124763150000000}$$
- $$\dfrac{2051563935160591194337436768610392837217226815379395891838337765936509 \pi }{4103129007448718822870650414175026723860506854636748901313920000000000}$$
- $$\dfrac{37193167701690492344448194533283488902041049236760438302965167901187323851384840067287863 \pi }{74386376780038719358535506076609218130495936637120586884474907521986965251324791250000000}$$

He states "The explanation for this change is a bit technical, but the critical reason is that $\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{5} + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{13} \lt 1$, whereas, adding the next term $\frac{1}{15}$ pushes the sum over $1$, making a difference in the value of the integral."

He does not mention the researcher, but I'd like to know what is a "bit technical" explanation or if there is a more analytical or mathematical rationale or a reference to the research?

Comment: This is an interesting example of "jumping to a conclusion."  (+1)

Comment: @MarkViola: Thanks. There is a post somewhere on the site that has a bunch of examples that are similar in nature, but I cannot find it at the moment,

Comment: A derivation of the integral is given on [Wiki::Borwein integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral#General_formula) which explains the result (i.e. why it suddenly fails to hold true once the sum of some series gets large enough)

Comment: A paper in the same spirit (formulas that holds for the first $N$ integers and then suddenly fails) might also be of interest ["Fun with large numbers"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3943v2.pdf) by R. Baillie.

Comment: @Winther Hi Hans.  Happy Holidays.  Thank you for the comments and embedded references!  Much appreciated.  -Mark

Comment: There's a variant of this identity that holds until 15,341,178,777,673,149,429,167,740,440,969,249,338,310,888 but fails at the next numbers :) see [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2018/09/a_pattern_that_eventually_fail.html).

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Excellent, thank you - I will have to play around with that one.

Comment: These ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111499), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/62474)) are the threads you are looking for.

Comment: woah!! I find this behavior truly remarkable (+1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{\sin(x / 3)}{x / 3} \frac{\sin(x / 5)}{x / 5} \cdots \frac{\sin(x / 15)}{x / 15} \ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674600/calculating-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-frac-sinx-3x-3-frac-si)

Comment: [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851U557j6HE) recently posted a video on this very thing

Comment: @user170231: Very nice video - thanks for that link!  I wonder what tool is used to do all those beautiful animations and to create a video like that.

Answer (score 8):

Sort of an answer.

These integrals are known as the Borwein Integrals, found by David and Johnathan Borwein in [*Some remarkable properties of sinc and related integrals* (2001)](https://carma.edu.au/resources/db90/pdfs/db90-119.00.pdf).

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral), if we have a sequence of nonzero reals $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$, we may evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty \prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\sin a_k x}{a_kx}dx=\frac{\pi}{2a_0}C_n,$$
where $$C_n=\frac{1}{2^nn!\prod_{k=1}^{n}a_k}\sum_{\gamma\in\{\pm1\}^n}\varepsilon_\gamma b_\gamma^n\text{ sgn}(b_\gamma),$$
$$\gamma=(\gamma_1,\gamma_2,...,\gamma_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n,\qquad \varepsilon_\gamma=\gamma_1\gamma_2\cdots\gamma_n,$$
and $$b_\gamma=a_0+a_1\gamma_1+a_2\gamma_2+\dots+a_n\gamma_n.$$
Then, apparently, when $a_0>|a_1|+|a_2|+\dots+|a_n|,$ we have $C_n=1$. I am not sure how this follows from the explicit evaluation, but I'll update when I find out.

Anyway, taking $a_k=\frac1{2k+1}$ and $J_n=\int_0^\infty\prod_{k=0}^{n}\sin(a_kx)/(a_kx)\, dx$, we get
$$J_1=\frac\pi2\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot\tfrac13}\left(\frac43-\frac23\right)=\frac\pi2,$$
$$J_2=\frac\pi2\cdot\frac1{2^2\cdot2\cdot\tfrac13\tfrac15}\left(\left(\frac{23}{15}\right)^2-\left(\frac{17}{15}\right)^2-\left(\frac{13}{15}\right)^2+\left(\frac{7}{15}\right)^2\right)=\frac\pi2,$$
and so on. As you can see, there are $2^n$ terms for $J_n$, and I don't wanna have to write out anymore of them.

Finally, when $n=7$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{7}|a_k|=\sum_{k=1}^{7}\frac1{2k+1}=\frac{46207}{45045}\approx 1.0218>a_0=1,$$ and indeed,
$$J_7\approx \frac\pi2-2.31\cdot10^{-11}.$$