# Looking for summation formula which holds true just for few terms

Tags: summation, induction

Some summtion formulas like $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and,

$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i} = 2- \frac{n+2}{2^n}$ hold and can be proven by induction.

However, I'm curious to know if there are any formulas that hold true only for the first few terms ($n \in [1,50]$), but fail to hold for larger values of $n$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Formulas" is too wide a concept. Nearly everything is a formula in some language. For a  sufficiently wide meaning you can put on the left many examples. Say, the number of coefficients  of the [cyclotomic polynomial of degree $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) of absolute value larger than $1$, and on the right put $0$. This formula holds for $n$ up to $104$.

Comment: There are interesting restrictions that can be considered that present the opposite phenomenon. For example, if the sides are [constant recursive sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence), then there is a finite number of terms to consider, that if they match, then the equation is true for all $n$.

Comment: There is the famous example of Borwein's integrals (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025772/399263), they can be modified to fail at larger $n$ than original $n=15$. 3b1b have a good video on these.

Comment: You may find many examples for $n \le 10$ if you take a simple function, compute first several elements and search at [the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org). For example I've found right now that the number of distinct sums $i^3 + j^3$ for $1 \le i \le j \le n$ [equals to $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ for $n \le 11$](https://oeis.org/A061791).