# Proving $F(z)=\prod _{k=0}^{\infty}\text{sinc} \left(\frac{\pi z}{2 k+1}\right) $ belongs to Schwartz space

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Denote
$$F(z)=\prod _{k=0}^{\infty}\text{sinc} \left(\frac{\pi z}{2 k+1}\right)=\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \cos \left(\frac{\pi z}{2 n}\right)$$

How can we prove $F\in S(\mathbb{R})$ (Schwartz space) ? I've already shown that $F(z)$ is entire and rapidly decreasing in strip $|\Im(z)|≤r$ for $r>0$.

Background: This arises from solving [Borwein integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674600/calculating-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-frac-sinx-3x-3-frac-si) via Fourier transform.

Comment: The naive bound fails but it is clear the solution is to show that $f(z)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\text{sinc} \left(\frac{\pi z}{2 k+1}\right)$ is entire 
and rapidly decreasing on the horizontal strips $|\Im(z)|\le r$ from which the Cauchy integral formula implies that all its derivatives are rapidly decreasing too, so that $f(t)$ is Schwartz and so is its inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @reuns Following your hint I've proved your first statement. Would you please elaborate the way of using Cauchy integral formula here? I didn't figure out how derivatives can be donimated.

Comment: Did you show that $|f(x+iy)|$ is bounded by a rapidly decrasing function $h(x)$ on a strip $|y|\le r$ ? Then $$f^{(k)}(x) = \frac{k!}{2i\pi} \int_{|s-x|=r/2} \frac{f(s)}{(s-x)^{k+1}}ds\le k! (r/2)^{k+1} h(x)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following reun's hint, $|f(x+iy)|$ is donimated by rapidly decreasing $h(x)$ on strip $\Im z\leq r$, $r>0$ ($\text{sinc}(z)=O(\frac{1}{x})$ on the strip as $x\to \infty$). Cauchy formula gives $|f^{(k)}|\leq k! (r/2)^{-k} h(x-r/2)$, thus all derivatives of $f$ are also rapidly decreasing, so $f\in S$.